# reading and storing data into a python data structure from a csv

Tags: python, csv

i am trying to figure out how to read my survey data but i keep getting this error. i feel like i am missing some things when i type out how to specifically find the file i need... and would a dictionary be the best data structure to use for this? the ultimate goal is: by using each voting method to determine a winner from the data that was collected. i plan on using if/else if statements...

[image: current code]

[image: error message]

Comment: Are you trying to read the csv or write to it?

Comment: You should add more info about your issue in order to get the correct answer. Also, don't use photos - instead add code to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your directory properly? The error says `No such file or directory`. Provide the full correct dir for your csv file and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to providing a full file path, you can put the csv file with the python script under the same folder and try.